# How to identify the image name using java code in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am placing image several places. Is any way to identify the image name using java code in android, not using id.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you need a shallow equality or a deep equality. Like in vanilla java, you could use the '==' operation to determine that you're looking at the same instance of an image as you expected. For deep equality, use .equals. That's how you "identify" all objects. Is there something special about these images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getResourceEntryName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) to get the name of the image from resources folder,

```
    String image_name = getResources().
                                   getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.good_morning);
    Log.d("image_name", image_name);
```

This will give the name of the image that is `good_morning` in this case.